# empty() everything except a particular element

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery's `empty()` method, can I prevent a particular element from being removed from the DOM, while all other elements are removed?

For instance:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="noRemove"></div>
    ... more content ...
</div>
```

When I make this call with jQuery `$("#container").empty()`, how can I prevent the removal of `noRemove` while still removing the rest of the content inside `container`?

Comment: how about `$('#container').find('*').not('#noRemove').remove();` ?

Comment: @manix: that won't work if `#noRemove` contains any other elements (they will be removed too).  It also won't delete any text nodes that are direct children of `#container`.

Comment: @jnylen oh! I have tested and you are correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't using the `empty` function alone. Here's one way you could do it:

```
var $container = $('#container'),
    $noRemove = $container.find('#noRemove');

$container.html($noRemove);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/R4cu5/

Comment: No problem. However, as is, I believe @João's answer is better as in the fact that it allows for multiple elements to be filtered out. Mine only allows for one.

Comment: Actually what I said is a lie. As long as you use a class selector in each of the elements you want to remove (as you should do in said case) this solution works just as well as @João 's. http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/R4cu5/4/

Comment: Yep, I'm using a class selector and it's working perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following, it will remove everything from the container *but* the element whose `id` is `noRemove`:

```
$('#container').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.id != "noRemove";
}).remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uTctB/)**.

Comment: I had previously answered the same thing with `.not()`, which does not work because it excludes any text nodes.

Comment: @jnylen: That's why you need to use `filter()` instead, which *will* process text nodes.

Comment: Agreed.  Is this documented anywhere?  I think it should be mentioned on the http://api.jquery.com/contents/ page.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I just used that involves table data being refreshed after an AJAX pull for a specific row. A bit of a vicarious answer.

```
$('.overrideFcstRow td').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('overrideTitle')){
        $(this).empty();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that this should do the trick:

```
$("#container").find(":not(#noRemove)").remove();
```

Comment: That approach won't work if `#noRemove` contains any other elements (they will be removed too). It also won't delete any text nodes that are direct children of `#container`.

Comment: You're right.  I'd go with @JOPLOmacedo's approach then--caching the node you want and re-inserting it back.